# How can I make the LinearProgress MUI and SnackBar autohide duration last the same time?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to fix my SnackBar with the LinearProgress so it matches its auto-hide duration set in 4 seconds. I've struggled to do it many hours but I couldn't find a proper solution so far. Is there any way to match auto-hide duration and LinerProgress  so that both last 4 seconds and then the snackBar closes automatically? I've used the code from MUI Linear Progress component. Maybe de issue is in the useEffect? I'm new to this so not 100% sure. Thanks for your suggestions!

This is my code:

```
interface SuccessMessageProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  title?: string;
  message?: string;
}

const SlideTransition = (props: SlideProps) => <Slide {...props} direction="left" />;

export const SuccessMessage = ({
  open,
  onClose,
  title = 'Title',
  message = 'Insert message here' }: SuccessMessageProps ) => {

  const { palette } = useTheme();

  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [showLinearProgress, setShowLinearProgress] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = (): void => {
    onClose();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((oldProgress) => {
        if (oldProgress === 100) {
          return 0;
        }
        const diff = Math.random() * 15;
        return Math.min(oldProgress + diff, 100);
      });
    }, 400);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      TransitionComponent={SlideTransition}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <div>
        <Alert
          sx={{
                width: '487px',
                height: '104px',
                paddingTop: '20px',
                paddingLeft: '20px',
                backgroundColor: '#FDFDFD',
          }}
          icon={(
            <Stack
              justifyContent="center"
              alignItems="center"
              style={{
            borderRadius: '100%',
            backgroundColor: alpha(palette.success.main, 0.10),
            width: '48px',
            height: '48px',
              }}
            >
              <CheckIcon
                size={24}
                color={palette.success.main}
              />
            </Stack>
          )}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <AlertTitle sx={{ paddingRight:'80px' }}>
            <Typography variant='headings.h4'>{title}</Typography>
          </AlertTitle>
          <Typography variant='captions.default'>{message}</Typography>
        </Alert>
        {!showLinearProgress
         && <LinearProgress variant="determinate" sx={{ color:'#222221' }} value={progress} />}
      </div>
    </Snackbar>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems I can't show a working example. The issue is that the SnackBar closes after 4 seconds but the Linear Progress lasts more, so how can I fix LinearProgress to be completed in 4 seconds too? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

We need to find first:

- what percentage is our step for the progress bar, since the value that we pass to the prop is representation of 0 - 100%
- after that we can add this step until we fill the bar to 100% or respectfully the time of 4 seconds ends
- in the beginning of the interval we set the snack bar state to visible and in the end of the interval we set it back to hidden, resetting the value of the progress bar to 0 as well

NB: There is react library which i think migth be very helpfull for future problems like this

- [react-timer-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timer-hook)

So, here is what i was able to create:

```
const [snackbarVisibility, setSnackbarVisibility] = useState(false);
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

const handleAction = () => {
  setSnackbarVisibility(true);

  // 10ms is what percentage(%) of 4000ms, equals to 0.25%
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setProgress((prevProgress) => prevProgress + 0.25);
  }, 10);
  
  // So, every 10ms we add 0.25 as a number to the value of the progress bar, until 4000ms/4s 
  // And since we calcualted the step, which is 0.25%, for 10ms of 4000ms, 
  // we can stop the progress bar and then hide the snack bar 
  // when the time of 4000ms lasts or when the value of the bar hits 100
  const duration = setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    setSnackbarVisibility(false);
    setProgress(0);
  }, 4000);

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(duration);
  };
};

return (
  <>
    <Snackbar open={snackbarVisibility} />
    <LinearProgress
      value={progress}
      valueBuffer={progress}
      variant="determinate"
    />
    <Button onClick={handleAction}>Start</Button>
  </>
);
```

NB2: This can be futher optimized , for sure.
[MUI Snackbar API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/snackbar/)
[MUI LinerProgress API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/linear-progress/)

Comment: Thank you so much. This looks good, but I can't add a button to the snackbar, is there any other way of triggering the progressbar instead of using an onClick?

Comment: Well thats for sure, but the question is very abstract, depends on what you are really trying to achive...

Comment: The progressBar has to finish when the authide finishes too, that's is 4 seconds duration. How can I reuse your code?

Comment: Don't use auto hide, set the open state of the snack bar to `false` after 4s, i have written it in the `handleAction()`

Comment: ok, then where should I use the handleAction function as I don't need the button?